# Run queue groups in the bull queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, queue, node-modules, bull-queue

I'm developing an application in nodejs, which manages queues in the bull, and it needs to make several HTTP requests asynchronously and then I need to get the result of these calls and perform a processing. Keep asking me if the bull could be useful for this task, how it can process several jobs and get the result of all to perform the processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can set concurrent in defining process.
Have a look here
https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull#separate-processes